# Not getting current user input value of input in Jquery Autocomplete with multiple inputs?

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

Hi I am using Jquery auto complete with multiple inputs tags. My problem is that i am not able to get current  user  input  value in my auto complete  function.

Here  is  my  code

```
 function Call() {

var str = $("#auto").val();
var substr = str.split(',');

$(".inputcatalog").each(function () {

    var classes = $(this).attr("class").split(" ");
    var id = classes[classes.length - 1];
    $this = $(this);

    var stype = id;
    var srctxt = $this.val();

    substr.forEach(function (item) {
        if (id == item) {
            AutoComplete($this, stype)
        }

    });


});


 }
```

//My Autocompete function

```
 function AutoComplete(object, filter) {

$this = object;
var stype = filter;
var srctxt = $this.val();
$this.autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.getJSON('/Cataloging/Bib/AutoComplete',
             {

                 stype: stype,
                 term: $this.val()
             }, response);
    },
    select: function (event, ui) {

        // Do something with "ui.item.Id" or "ui.item.Name" or any of the other properties you selected to return from the action
    }
});

 }
```

my term  value  is  empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

within source function the `request` argument is an object with `term` as property:

Try using:

```
term: request.term
```

instead of

```
term: $this.val()
```

API Reference: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source